# What's the first anime and manga to use the sweat drop to indicate embarrassment or similar atmosphere?

Tags: anime-history, manga-history

Nowadays, many animes use the sweat drop to indicate an atmosphere of embarrassment like the following examples. But what's the first anime and manga to use the sweat drop to indicate embarrassment or similar atmosphere? Did this sweat drop idea originate in Japan or cartoons in other country?

From *5-toubun no Hanayome*
[image]

From *Kanojo mo Kanojo*
[image]

Comment: ? - https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SweatDrop